# shutil not working in python with a function call

Tags: python

I have a function which is merging certain files from a directory

```
def merge(path):
    f = open("indexFile","w")
    for path,directory,files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            f1 = open(os.path.join(path,file))
            createCatFile(f1.read())
            print "merging files"
            shutil.copyfileobj(f1, f)
            f1.close()
    f.close()
```

Before copying the file object, it is passing the contents of f1 to a function to do some processing. The problem is that the indexFile is created but there is not data in the file. it is an empty file. The `createCatFile()` function works perfectly as expected. Also, "merging files" is printed number of times the `merge()` function is called. When I remove the function call to `createCatFile()` the indexFile is created successfully.

Any help as to what is the problem with this?

The createCatFile function does the following:

```
def createCatFile(wordtodocstr):
    global offset
    wordInfo = wordtodocstr.split()
    term = wordInfo[0]
    newtermid = wordInfo[1]
    docList = wordInfo[2::2]
    ctfList = [int(number) for number in wordInfo[3::2]]
    docfr = len(docList)
    wordctf = sum(ctfList)
    catFileList = [term, newtermid, str(offset), str(wordctf), str(docfr)]
    catFileJoin = " ".join(catFileList)
    with open(path2+term, "w") as foutterm:
        foutterm.write(catFileJoin)
        foutterm.close()    
    offset+=1
```

Thank you.

Comment: If `createCatFile` is the problem, can you actually post its contents?

Comment: @thantos: The documentation [explains all](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj).

Comment: @Blender: I have edited my question to show what does createCatFile does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe doing `f1.read()` "consumes" the file, and nothing is left for shutil to copy. Try `f1.seek(os.SEEK_SET)` to rewind the file before calling copyfileobj

Comment: This solves the problem. I was unaware that f1.read() consumes the file. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

From [shutil.copyfileobj](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/shutil.html) documentation:

> Copy the contents of the file-like object fsrc to the file-like object
> fdst. The integer length, if given, is the buffer size. In particular,
> a negative length value means to copy the data without looping over
> the source data in chunks; by default the data is read in chunks to
> avoid uncontrolled memory consumption. **Note that if the current file
> position of the fsrc object is not 0, only the contents from the
> current file position to the end of the file will be copied.**

So basically what everyone is saying, read moves the position pointer to the EOF, thus giving the copyfileobj method a file with nothing to read.

It is not your function that is causing the problem it is the f.read().

Answer (score 0):

`f1.read()` consumes `f1`. Either don't do that, or seek back to the beginning first.

Comment: Did the f1.seek(os.SEEK_SET) to rewind the operation. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you are jumping to the end of the file after you call `.read()` on the file object.

Before you try copying the file object, try to move back to the beginning:

```
f1.seek(0)
```